# Stokes' theorem - limits of integration

Tags: integration, stokes-theorem

I am trying to evaluate a $\int_\gamma \vec{F}.d\vec{r}$ integral using Stokes' theorem, but I can't visualize the limits I should use in order to integrate properly. The curve $\gamma$ is the intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and $x+y+z=0$, and I am using the sphere as the surface to apply Stokes' theorem. Then:

$(x,y,z)=(a\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta},a\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta},a\cos{\phi})$

But what are the limits? Working with this parametrization and the plane's equation, I got $\tan{\phi}=-\frac{1}{\sin{\theta}+\cos{\theta}}$, what should I do with this relation?

Thanks

Comment: You should show us your $\vec F$. Unless there is something special about it there is nothing gained by applying Stokes' theorem.

Comment: $\vec{F} = y \vec{i} + z \vec{j} + x \vec{k}$.

Comment: The curve $\gamma$ is not the boundary of a sphere.

Comment: I know, but I parametrized the surface of the sphere with edge on the curve in order to apply Stokes' theorem. I have tried with a plane, but I got to a tricky integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall take advantage of the  fact that ${\rm curl}(\vec F)=(-1,-1,-1)$ is constant and parallel to the normal $n={1\over\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$ of the plane $P:\>x+y+z=0$.

The curve $\gamma$ bounds a circular disk $D$ of radius $a$ in $P$. Using Stokes' theorem and writing ${\rm d}\omega$ for the surface element on $D$ we then obtain
$$\int_\gamma\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\pm \int_D{\rm curl}(\vec F)\cdot n\>{\rm d}\omega=\pm\sqrt{3}\int_D{\rm d}\omega=\pm\sqrt{3}\pi a^2\ ,$$
depending on the orientation of $\gamma$, which was not specified in the givens.